# Paperclip - how to set up the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, path, paperclip

I am already a long time struggling with setting a path for storing an images.
I would like to have a path in a shape:

> public/photos/88/small/image.jpg
>
> public/photos/88/medium/image.jpg
>
> public/photos/88/original/image.jpg

The number **88** is ID of image gallery. I tried to check some tutorials on google, but I can't find the right way, how to set it.

I am trying in my **Photo** model:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => {:small=> "65x65#",
                                :medium  => "500x500>" },
                    :url => "/public/photos/:album_id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

So my first problem is, I don't know, how to get to **Photo** model the value of **album_id**, and the second one, how to distinguish the directories for **small**, **medium** and **original** size of image...

Can anyone help me, please, how the path set up?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807063/paperclip-tips-and-updates

And don't forget restart your server! (my problem)

Comment: This isn't an answer - can you please update it in case the link is dead?